# How to align differently a specific <div> in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for my layout and after completing [Flexbox Froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/) I tried to get the following alignment:

[image]

My thinking is the following:

- the boxes (`<div>`) need to flow in a column: `flex-direction: column;`
- they are aligned top-down: `align-content: flex-start;`
- one specific box [aligns itself](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-self/) to the bottom: `align-self: flex-end;`

This leads to the HTML code below (also available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acoqoors/))

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    box 1
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    box 2
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    box 3
  </div>
</div>
```

with the CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.box3 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

But it does not work - it looks like to third box is pushed (`flex-end`) to the right and not to the bottom.

[image]

My understanding was that `align-self` handles an exception relative to the container (*"the container aligns everything from the top, but I, myself, will align to the bottom"*). Isn't that so?

Comment: Note that `align-self` works along the cross axis, since the flex-direction is column, it works correctly. You also need to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties

Comment: @ManojKumar: thank you - I now understand why the alignment to the end was actually to the right. I was misunderstanding how `align-self`worked. The question (and answers) you link to are fantastic;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `align-self`, you can do this with `margin-auto`.

[Flexbox's Best-kept secret](https://medium.com/@samserif/flexbox-s-best-kept-secret-bd3d892826b6#.w748krjtq)

[**W3C Spec: Auto Margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 150px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
.box3 {
  margin-top: auto;
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    box 1
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    box 2
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
    box 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is something new for me. Why isn't the whole box green in your example (even though the margin for box3 reaches up to box2)? Is there a property to set the color of the margin? I just saw `background`and `border`

Comment: Margins don't have colour. They represent the space between elements.

Comment: Note: this only worked when I forcefully set the `height` of the container.

Comment: That would be standard for flexbox columns...they all require a height limitation.

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate approach would be to give your container a height in Percentage rather than Pixels if that's what you want.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 100%;
}

.box3 {
  margin: auto 0;
}
```